# Standalone jQuery or MooTools version of YooTools YOOcarousel

Tags: slideshow

I was wondering if anyone knows of a jQuery or MooTools script that will do the exact same thing as YOOcarousel (http://tools.yootheme.com/extensions/yoocarousel).

I'm looking to emulate the 'List Styling' setup they have where on the left you have the tabbed navigation and on the right it fades in/out thru each of the tabbed items as they are clicked.

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 0):

[iCarousel](http://zendold.lojcomm.com.br/icarousel/) might work for your purposes (demo and code examples here as well), created by Fabio Zendhi Nagao. The functionality isn't exactly identical (tab based control) to the YooTools Carousel but foundation is there to make it very close to the YooTools offering.

[slideItMoo](http://www.php-help.ro/examples/mootools_rotator/) is another alternative- however, it appears to have fewer customized examples and less of a fan base.